# It is possible to know if the browser supports a "svg" format, otherwise, show "png"?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, canvas

good afternoon, I would like to know if it is possible to identify if a feature is available in the user's browser, and if it is not compatible, it offers a similar compatible feature.

Sorry for my english, i'm using google translator.

Comment: SVG is supported in all major browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: For a more general solution, something like https://modernizr.com/ (which includes a detector for SVG support)

Comment: The mention of SVG and PNG was just one example.

Comment: Then you should've picked a more suitable question title. Either way, Modernizr or something similar is what you want for feature detection.